# Unable to enable Identity Platform on Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, migration, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

We currently use Google Identity Toolkit on a web project on Google App Engine.  We need to migrate to Google Identity Platform or Firebase Auth since Toolkit is being deprecated.  Every time I work up the nerve to work on it, I get stuck at the first step:  trying to enable it as per the instructions:

https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/migrate-identityplatform

The issue occurs at step 2 of "Before you Begin" where I am supposed to 'Enable Identity Platform.'  When doing so I get a message stating

> "We are unable to enable Identity Platform on your project, please try
>   again later."

I've gotten the same message every time I've tried for the past couple months.  I think I've officially waited until "later" and now need some help.

Any advice?  Happy to provide more info.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix it? Having the same issue...