# Google Cloud Identity Platfrom doesn't get enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Trying to enable Google Cloud Identity Platform but I get an error message that the platform cannot be enabled. Do you know why?

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the steps you are performing and more detail on the messages produced?

Comment: How do you enable the cloud identity platform? Can you paste the error message ? did you follow [this documentation?](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/quickstart-cicp)

Comment: do you have the needed permissions to set up the identity platform for the project you are using?

Comment: @Alioua these are the steps that I follow. The error message that I get when clicking on "Enable Identity Platform" blue button is: We're unable to enable Identity Platform on your project. Please, try again later.

Comment: @PaddyPopeye, I am not sure what permissions do I need and how can I check whether I have them. Any guidance will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/access-control  https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access

Answer (score 0):

To Enable Identity platforms you need to enable a Firebase in your project.

Please check the similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620069/unable-to-enable-identity-platform-on-google-cloud) , where identity platform enabling issues resolved by enabling the firebase services.

To enable the cloud identity platform you need to be a project owner with billing enabled. please check the [document](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/quickstart-cicp#before_you_begin)

Comment: I have firebase incl authentication enabled and it works through firebase but the issue with identity platform still persists.